# the type or namespace name 'web pages' does not exist in the namespace 'microsoft.web'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am stuck in my project with error mentioned above. I have tried `copy local=true` and `<private>true</private>` multiple times but it does not fix my issue. I have others error like this one, which are:

```
The type or namespace name 'Transcations' does not exist in the namespace 'system'

the type or namespace name 'web matrix' does not exist in the namespace 'system'

the type or namespace name 'optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'system.web'

Error   18  The type or namespace name 'IMigrationMetadata' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   23  The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   2   The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Error   3   The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  

Error   4   The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Error   6   The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

and many more....

I have all nuget packages. Kindly help me out.

Comment: i am not missing any using directive, and errors appear in so many files, that is why i could not paste them here !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.113).aspx), the `System.Data.Entity` namespace is contained in the `EntityFramework.dll` assembly. Open the [Package Manager](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) in Visual Studio and run this command to install it via NuGet.

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Comment: Thanks , i have installed it, what should i do about other errors ? Like: websecurity, OAuthwebsecurity, web pages, web matrix, optimization, etc !

Comment: Please read my answer and see the line of reasoning I used. I first checked the documentation on MSDN to see what assembly contains the items in the namespace I'm looking for. Then I search NuGet for the appropriate package, then I install it. You should try this process for your remaining errors. And if the packages aren't in NuGet, then try using the "Add Reference" option when you right click your project in VS. Also, check the capitalization of your `using` statements to make sure they're correct.

Comment: Thanks, i have almost remove all errors but facing two of them which are:   1) Error 2 The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 2) Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Comment: and one warning: Warning 3 Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed

Comment: @EM923 `System.Web.Http` seems to be in [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Http/) NuGet package. For your conflicting versions of dependent assembly, that's a separate issue that you should post a new question for after you can't figure it out. Make sure you provide enough detail in your new question.